# I don't understand how to fix this function in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm getting the following error in Visual Studio that I don't understand:

```
main.cpp(21): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'void' to 'char'
main.cpp(21): note: Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types
```

This is my code:

```
void getLetterGrade(double totalAvg, char& letter_Grade)
{
    if (totalAvg >= 90) {
        letter_Grade = 'A';
    }
    else if (totalAvg < 90 && totalAvg >= 80) {
        letter_Grade = 'B';
    }
    else if (totalAvg < 80 && totalAvg >= 70) {
        letter_Grade = 'C';
    }
    else if (totalAvg < 70 && totalAvg >= 60) {
        letter_Grade = 'F';
    }
}

int main()
{
    double totalGrade = 74;
    char letterGRADE;
    letterGRADE = getLetterGrade(totalGrade, letterGRADE);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], along with a description of the symptoms you observe, sample input to trigger your observation, the observed output in contrast to the output you expect.

Comment: First of all your condition doesn't need the `totalAvg < 90 &&` (etc.) part. That's kind of implied by the conditions. Secondly, what happens if `totalAvg < 60`? You don't have any plain `else`.

Comment: What is the problem? Please show a [mre] with the full error message

Comment: Just use `getLetterGrade(totalGrade, letterGRADE);` you are passing `letterGRADE` by reference and returning void so you can't/don't need to assign the result to `letterGRADE`

Comment: The function should return a value, not store it in a reference argument.

Comment: Get yourself a [decent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 4):

Your function `getLetterGrade` returns `void`, that means "nothing". Therefore it is illegal to use it on the right hand side of an assignment.

This here

```cpp
letterGRADE = getLetterGrade(totalGrade, letterGRADE);
```

will result in an error, because it tries to use the return value of the function, but there is none.

But, since you pass the second parameter *by reference* (by saying "char **&** letter_Grade") you already get the required letter back. Just change your code to

```cpp
getLetterGrade(totalGrade, letterGRADE);
```

and you should be fine. The value of the variable `letterGRADE` will already have been updated when the called function returns.

As an alternative, you could change the function to return the letter instead:

```cpp
char getLetterGrade(double totalAvg)
{
    char letter_Grade = '?';
    if (totalAvg >= 90)
    {
        letter_Grade = 'A';
    }
    else if (totalAvg < 90 && totalAvg >= 80)
    {
        letter_Grade = 'B';
    }
    else if (totalAvg < 80 && totalAvg >= 70)
    {
        letter_Grade = 'C';
    }
    else if (totalAvg < 70)
    {
        // Anything below 70 is flunked, so no need to give an upper limit (otherwise an average of 50 would not get a mark at all)
        letter_Grade = 'F';
    }
    return letter_Grade;
}
```

Now you would call it like so, using a return value:

```cpp
letterGRADE = getLetterGrade(totalGrade);
```